# want to navigate to specific chapter in flatlist paging react natve

Tags: react-native, pagination, scrollview, flatlist, ibooks

I have a flat list with horizontal and paging being enabled. it basically contains chapters of books. I can access any page I want To store the last page read by `user.pagination` also occurs on font size bases so that when the font is large some data moves next page. but the problem is there should also be an option to navigate to specific chapters which I moment dont know how to do. can please give a solution? much appreciated

```
const handleMomentumScrollEnd = (event) => {
    
    const offsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset
    console.log("off set y",offsetY);
    const index = Math.round(offsetX / Dimensions.get('window').width);
    console.log("handle momentum",index);
    setSelectedPageIndex(index);
    console.log("handle momment scroll end");
  };

  const renderContentPages = (item) => {

    const words = item.content.split(' ');
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(words.length / wordsPerPage);

    return Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, pageIndex) => {
      const startIdx = pageIndex * wordsPerPage;
      const endIdx = startIdx + wordsPerPage;
      const pageWords = words.slice(startIdx, endIdx).join(' ');

      return (
        <View key={pageIndex} style={{width:contentWidth}}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={ [{padding:30, fontSize:fontSizeOfBookRead,fontWeight:fontWeightOfBookRead }]}>{pageWords}</Text>
          <Text>{pageIndex+1 }</Text>
          <Text>{item.title.split(" ")[1]}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  <FlatList
     style={{width:contentWidth}}
     horizontal
     pagingEnabled
     data={filteredChapters} // 
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.chapId.toString()}
     onMomentumScrollEnd={handleMomentumScrollEnd}
     ref={scrollViewRef}
     renderItem={({ item }) => (
        renderContentPages(item)
     )}/>
```

Comment: What does `filteredChapters ` look like. An array of objects? What is the `typeof filteredChapters`

Comment: Thanks for generous response Yes it's an array of objects with chapter id. Chapter title And chapter contents